# Symfony Error -Cannot access private property AppBundle\Entity\VacancyEntity::$jobDescription

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, symfony-2.8

I got this error when I try to access fetch result in symfony 2.8. Here is my code

```
 public function staticAction(Request $request)
    {   


      $jobid = $this->get('session')->get('jobid');
      $jobDetails = $this->getVacancyData($jobid);
      echo "<pre>";
      var_dump($jobDetails);
      $description = $jobDetails->jobDescription;


      return $this->render('FrontEnd/job.html.twig', array('jobdetails' => $jobDetails ));
    }

    public function getVacancyData($id){

        $vacancy = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository(VacancyEntity::class)
        ->findOneBy(array('id' => $id));


        if (!$vacancy) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException();
        }else{
            return $vacancy;
        }  

    }
```

Error occurred in below line,

```
$description = $jobDetails->jobDescription;
```

How to solve this?

Comment: You're missing some basics on OOP, have a look there for some more information on visibility http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that you need to call a getter like this:

```
$description = $jobDetails->getJobDescription();
```

Because in your entities properties are private, so you need to use a getter

I don't know if in you entity there is a getter with name getJobDescription but it should be there a function that return property `jobDescription`